# Parametric typing based on the value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type for my forms.
Something like this:

```
function getCiccio<Values extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>({
  defaultValue,
  onSubmit
}: {
  defaultValue: Values
  onSubmit: (values: Values) => void
}): {
  value: Values
  onSubmit: (value: Values) => void
} {
  return {
    value: defaultValue,
    onSubmit
  }
}

const a = getCiccio({
  defaultValue: { cane: 1 },
  onSubmit: (a) => { // here a is typed 
    alert(1)
  }
})
```

I would like to have the value, on the `onSubmit` function interfere from the `initialValue` object.
Is it possible?
This is what i have done so far. But In order to have the `a` on the `onSubmit` function typed, I need to call a function.
I would love to have a normal inferface.

Comment: By `initialValue`, do you meant `initialValues` ?
You will increase your chances to get the answer if you share minimum reproducable example of your code

Comment: done, I have added an example

Comment: I don't see variable `initialValue` at all in your example

Answer (score 0):

If you define the interface:

```
interface Ciccio <T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>> {
  value: T
  onSubmit( value: T ): void
}
```

Then you can use that interface to automatically give the typing in the `onSubmit` function when you define a new object:

```
const newCiccio: Ciccio <{ cand: number }> = {
  value: { cand: 1 },
  onSubmit: function( arg ) {
    // arg is typed here
  }
}
```

However, it is essential here to specify the type when defining the new value if you want the type to be more specific than the general and default `Record<string, unknown>`. So if you require the type in the `onSubmit` function to be inferred without it being provided as a type argument when specifying the interface (ie if you'd like to replace `Ciccio <{ cand: number }>` with simply `Ciccio`), I don't believe this is possible without defining a function as in your original approach.

Comment: yes, I get what you are saying.
We ended at the same conclusion!